# Deleting in Django Admin throws a 403 error

Tags: django, django-admin, http-status-code-403

I am attempting to delete a record from the Django admin interface. I click the check box then select "Delete Selected " from the action drop down and select 'Go'. This immediately throws a 403 error.

This is the area I am attempting to delete from that gets the 403s:

[image: Failing delete area]

The model that is having problems deleting has two inline elements. However, will allow me to delete if I go to each individual record and select delete from there.

It works from here (after clicking 'Third' from the above image)

[image: Working delete area]

I watched the request in Firebug and it does not seem different than when I delete a record on a different model and it works.

This is the output of Firebug:

```
Parameters                   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    _selected_action         2
    action                   delete_selected
    csrfmiddlewaretoken      lr6EAAPGJWJBWIm6NxIoyt8fWzfuNxj9
    index                    0
    select_across            0

Source
csrfmiddlewaretoken=lr6EAAPGJWJBWIm6NxIoyt8fWzfuNxj9&action=delete_selected&select_across=0&index=0&_selected_action=2
```

I am unsure where to go to troubleshoot this error since I haven't modified the admin panel at all and the only thing in the logs is a 403 error. How can I get the delete at the model level to work?

**Edit** I have delete permissions to this model. It also occurs if the user deleting is the superuser.

Comment: Could you post the relevant model / admin code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this in a way that I wanted. I would have liked to keep the ability to delete from the overview page, but since it worked if I deleted an individual entry one at a time, I settled for this work around.

Add `actions = None` to the admin.py that contains this model. This removes the action drop down, preventing a user from selecting an option that will throw the 403 error.